# robots txt file syntax can I dis allow all then only allow some sites

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Can you disallow all and then allow specific sites only.  I am aware one approach is to disallow specific sites and allow all.  Its is valid to do the reverse: E.G:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /siteOne/
Allow: /siteTwo/
Allow: /siteThree/
```

To simply disallow all and then allow sites seems much more secure than to all all and them have to think about all the places you dont want them to crawl.

could this method above be responsible for the sites description saying 'A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more.' in the organic ranking on Google's home page

UPDATE - I have gone into Google webmaster tools > Crawl > robots.txt tester.  At first when I entered siteTwo/default.asp it said Blocked and highlighted the 'Disallow: /' line.  After leaving and re visiting the tool it now says Allowed.  Very weird. So if this says Allowed I wonder why it gived the message above in the description for the site?

UPDATE2 - The example of the robots.txt file above should have said dirOne, dirTwo and not siteOne, siteTwo. Two great links to know all about robot.txt are unor's robot.txt specification in the accepted answer below and the [robots exclusion standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) is also a must read.  This is all explained in these two pages.  In summary yes you can disallow and them allow BUT always place the disallow last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: You don’t disallow/allow crawling of "sites" in the robots.txt, but URLs. The value of `Disallow`/`Allow` is [always the beginning of a URL path](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/50711/17633).)

The [robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) does not define `Allow`.
Consumers following this specification would simply ignore any `Allow` fields. Some consumers, like Google, extend the spec and understand `Allow`.

- For those consumers that don’t know `Allow`: Everything is disallowed.
- For those consumers that know `Allow`: Yes, your robots.txt should work for them. Everything’s disallowd, except those URLs matched by the `Allow` fields.

Assuming that your robots.txt is hosted at `http://example.org/robots.txt`, Google would be **allowed** to crawl the following URLs:

- `http://example.org/siteOne/`
- `http://example.org/siteOne/foo`
- `http://example.org/siteOne/foo/`
- `http://example.org/siteOne/foo.html`

Google would **not be allowed** to crawl the following URLs:

- `http://example.org/siteone/` (it’s case-sensitive)
- `http://example.org/siteOne` (missing the trailing slash)
- `http://example.org/foo/siteOne/` (not matching the beginning of the path)

Comment: HI unor thank you for your time.  I have accepted this becasue its got value and I/my research agrees with most of it.  For anyone accepting this as an answer please also read the info in the second update to the original post